# How to externally control stroke of SVG pattern

Tags: svg, stroke

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 192 96" height="480" fill="none" stroke="#000">
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="gradInner" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop stop-color="#070" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="#007" offset="1"/>
     </linearGradient>

    <g id="shape-s">
      <path d="M48,4.5 H4.5 V43.5 H48"/>
      <path d="M48,9 H24 A15,15 0 0,0 24,39 H48" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
    <pattern id="shape-m" width="48" height="48" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M0,4.5H48M0,43.5H48"/>
      <path d="M0,9H48M0,39H48" stroke-width="2"/>
    </pattern>
    <g id="shape-e">
      <path d="M 0,4.5 H43.5 V43.5 H0"/>
      <path d="M 0,9 H24 A15,15 0 0,1 24,39 H0" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
    <g id="shape">
      <rect  fill="url(#shape-m)" stroke="none" x="48" width="48" height="48"/>
      <use xlink:href="#shape-s"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#shape-e" x="96"></use>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="url(#gradInner)">
    <path d="M48,4.5 H4.5 V43.5 H48"/>
    <path d="M48,4.5H96M48,43.5H96"/>
    <path d="M96,4.5 h43.5 v39 H96"/>
    <path d="M48,9 H24 A15,15 0 0,0 24,39 H48" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path d="M48,9H96M48,39H96" stroke-width="2"/>
    <path d="M96,9 h24 a15,15 0 0,1 0,30 H96" stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#shape" y="48" stroke="url(#gradInner)"/>
</svg>
```

I am thinking that this is not possible, but I want to fish for a solution here before I throw in the towel. I am creating `<use>` elements with dynamic widths in JavaScript. I do it by grouping 3 elements: start/left, middle, end/right. The start element is always the same. The end element is positions by the `x` attribute of the `<use>`.  The middle element is a `<rect>` filled with a `<pattern>` url.

The pattern was the only way I could see to be truly dynamic in width and support any kind of shape. But patterns also have serious limitations.  The first problem is that the `<rect>` using the pattern must have no stroke of its own. The bigger problem is that I cannot control the stroke from the `<use>` element, I must set the `stroke` attribute on the `<pattern>` element itself. (of course the same limitations apply to fill as stroke)

Is there another solution for this? I want to be able to apply a gradient to the `<use>` element as a whole.  A pattern does not allow for this.  I can work around that, but it's clumsy and I'd rather not.  Is there another solution for dynamic width that meets my needs?

Comment: I would like to understand better what you need to achieve. The shape you want to draw can be achieved with a very thick line with a `stroke-linecap="round"`

Comment: @enxaneta - I am building grids of these shapes in different widths, based on external data.  I want the shapes to be externally defined too, allowing for as much flexibility as possible.  I want to be able to apply a horizontal gradient to the shape as a whole, or at least achieve that appearance.  Patterns seem like the only way to do the middle, variable-width segment, while maintaining flexibility in terms of the shape being defined.
In terms of the round linecap, that's only because this is a simple example. The shape is user defined.

Comment: also note: The "round linecap" inner shape is to be filled from behind at varying opacity values. Thus the outer shape here uses `fill-rule="evenodd"`, and a stroke with a linecap doesn't work, at least for these outer shapes.

Comment: I'm near the end of my prototype and the reason I need this is for gradients on the rectangle that uses the repeated pattern.  I see no way to size the rectangle dynamically, repeating the pattern 1 or more times, and have the gradient use the rectangle width as its space.  The gradient is applied in the pattern.  The only way I see to enable dynamic width is by not using patterns and rectangles, instead grouping/cloning those pattern paths and repeating the contents of the paths' d attributes as if they were a pattern. My case is limited by only left-to-right repetition, which helps somewhat.